# Serilog - Splitting the log files using Correlation ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, serilog, serilog-aspnetcore

How to split the log file based on correlation ID enricher?

I have configured the correlation ID enricher but I want to create log files based on correlation ID.
(Example: fisjdbs-13727-hrjsb).

It needs to write all the logs for that ID into fjsjdbs-13727-hrjsb.log

Please suggest some approaches.

Comment: There's a Serilog.Sinks.Map - you should be able to do it with that. As for whether it's a good idea...

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this in .NET6

```
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
                .Enrich.WithCorrelationId()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .WriteTo.Map("CorrelationId", (id,wt) => wt.File($"{id}.log"))
                .CreateLogger();

        builder.Host.UseSerilog(log);
```

and you can see files are getting generated based on "CorrelationId".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. Tried this but is it possible to set output format? I cannot find outputFormat property for WriteTo.Map. If you know any approaches, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by output format, your ques did not mention about any format.

Comment: Please accept the ans if this solves the issue for splitting logs based on correlationid. For different issue ask a different question